# remove blank space where sidebar was

Tags: php, css

I have been working on a website using WordPress http://1stgoringheath.org.uk/, there are some pages that I didn't want to have the sidebar on, so I made a template and removed  get_sidebar

Now I have just a blank area where the sidebar was, which I want to remove and allow the main content div fill the space.

The pictures below show the empty space

[With Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzciX.png)

[Without Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaPsj.png)

How can I fill the empty space where the sidebar was?

Thanks

Links to page.php and style.css are below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aVTgmO9uuJtbXlofDeS-bDSxsRawj2vd/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pV6OW5b0WlipUrs0fAWZAXBcLoR1_n14/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You give us to see two different pages — "with" and "without", "home" and "Contact Us".

Comment: can you give us the link of your site ?

Comment: http://1stgoringheath.org.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add this code to your custom CSS :

```
.page-template-pageWithOutSidebar .entry-header, .page-template-pageWithOutSidebar .entry-content {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the parent container of the section whose left margin has to be removed add a 
class= "row ", and then in the child div element class = "col - * - 12"; , and then put 
* as md or sm or anything as required.

Answer (score -1):

You can only remove the blank space by editing the custom css. First you need to be working on a Child's theme to ensure your theme's update do not reverse your changes. Then find the main class and set the width to 100%. A link to your website can help us give you further assistance

Comment: A link is in the original post

Comment: Where would the custom css go would it be in the edited template, or the style.css